# ASP.net project parser error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-parsing

Zipped up my application for a university assignment and now suddenly it wont work???I Used visual studio to create a class diagram and added assosciations, could this have altered the code?

Below is the error i get when i try launch in browser..

Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication4.MvcApplication'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

i get this error when i try build my project

Error   2   The type 'WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheetsDBContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheetsDBContext' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'. G:\Software\Projects\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\Migrations\Configuration.cs    8   27  WebApplication4

Answer (score 0):

// First guess was: Try changing CodeBehind to CodeFile.

**Update** (question was updated)

(1) A "/" at the end of line 8 is not syntactically correct. (Does it look the same in your code? Would be fine know to the rest of the line including the closing '>',)

```
... sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration
     <WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheetsDBContext/
```

(2) Let's assume that the ´/´ was just a typo and your code contains a ´>´ instead. `DbMigrationsConfiguration` has this signature:

```
public class DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> 
   : DbMigrationsConfiguration where TContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
```

The class `CoreSheetsDBContext` which you pass as a generic parameter must be a subclass of `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`. Check that `CoreSheetsDBContext` actually inherits from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`. I.e. it should look like this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public class CoreSheetsDBContext : DbContext { ... }
```

Comment: Error 2 The type 'WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheetsDBContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheetsDBContext' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'. G:\Software\Projects\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\Migrations\Configuration.cs 8 27 WebApplication4

Comment: Your problem seems to be a simple type mismatch: WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheetsDBContext is not of expected type System.Data.Entity.DbContext. Just check line 8 in Configuration.cs.

Comment: '   internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WebApplication4.Models.CoreSheetsDBContext/'

Comment: that is my line 8, what should it be?

Comment: Please check if CoreSheetsDBContext should inherit from  System.Data.Entity.DbContext. This would resolve your type mismatch. What are the current superclasses of CoreSheetsDBContext?

Comment: I dont think it should? how do i check the super classes?